# Adding and Deleting row from table in JSP and update them in Spring MVC form's list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a bit new to Spring MVC, so need to your help on updating the form in spring mvc !!

I am working on Spring MVC based application. I have an "`updateForm`" and this form contains one list named `listOfMyCustomObjects`, i am using this list to iterate in jsp using JSTL, so i am able to view all the records present in the list.

Now the requirement is:

I have to provide the option to Add/Delete the records from the table, so i have coded for Adding/removing the records from table using javascript.(Just from view the records are getting added/deleted).

I have to update the Addition/Deletion of records in `updateForm` as well.

Note: Addition/Deletion of records is temporary on the screen, and finally there is a save button which will hit the controller.

So, Please guide me, how can i update the Added/Deleted record in my spring mvc `updateForm`, so that when 'SAVE' button is pressed, the request should have the correct `listOfMyCustomObjects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically 2 ways of doing that :

- the *javascript* way : keep in javascript a list of all deletions an insertions and send it to controller using Json, something like `{ 'del' : [ 'id1', 'id2', ...], 'add' : [ { 'key1' : 'val1', ...}, { 'key1' : 'val1', ...}, ...]}`. The controller takes it and passes the 2 lists to the service layer which delete and insert lines in only single transaction.
- the *submit* way : the controller receives a copy of what is displayed on screen and passes it to the service layer. The service layer deletes all lines not present (maybe through a full select of ids) and insert lines that have no id.

First way requires more work in client side, because you have to keep the history of what happened. Second requires mode work in server side because you have to find what lines have been deleted.

Comment: We have web services in the backend and they're already developed, so i was also thinking about the option1(JSON)...that way something can be done :) Much Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The sam ecan be achieved by 'clone()' method of `Jquery`.

1.) Create an empty Div -> row.

2.) Have a '+' button, and clone it using baove function.

3.) Reset the indexes of your list.

4.) For deleting the records if they are `persisted`, need to fire ajax call, if not `persisted` just delete from `DOM`.

Better solution can be to have a `child jsp` page included inside `parent page`. Here child will refer to `list<object>`, for every `CRUD opertion` just fire the `ajax call`, do all the manipulation and return the child page in reponse.

Refresh only this particular DIV contating `chile JSP` to display list. (Using `JSTL`)